php redis module and php compile mismatch
I am trying to install php-redis via pecl.
Running this:
php -i | grep API

gives this: PHP API => 20220829
I then run pecl install redis and I get the message:
...
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20220829
Zend Module Api No:      20220829
Zend Extension Api No:   420220829
...
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php/20230831/redis.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/redis-6.0.2
Extension redis enabled in php.ini

As you can see, there is a mismatch between the apis.
When I inspect php with php -i | grep redis, I get this error message:
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: redis: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20230831
PHP    compiled with module API=20220829
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

I am on php8.2, so api 20220829 is correct.
My question is, how can I install redis for api 20220829 to match my php version.

found this in my command line history: update-alternatives --get-selections | grep -e php -e pear -e pecl -e phar.

Your system is not just pulling 20230831 out of the air, so it appears that you have multiple versions of PHP installed. 20230831 is for PHP 8.3.
% php -v
PHP 8.3.10 (cli) (built: Aug  2 2024 15:31:39) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group

% php -i | grep API
PHP API => 20230831

I'm guessing that you've likely got php pointing to one version and php-config pointing to another. You can verify this by running php-config, to make sure it matches what php outputs:
% php-config
Options:
  --extension-dir     [/usr/lib/php/20230831]
  --phpapi            [20230831]
  --version           [8.3.10]

To rectify, you'll have to run alternatives for all the php utilities, not just php itself. I simplify this with a few aliases in my .bashrc:
alias php74='sudo -- sh -c "for P in php php-config phpize phar phar.phar; do update-alternatives --set \$P /usr/bin/\${P}7.4; done"'
alias php80='sudo -- sh -c "for P in php php-config phpize phar phar.phar; do update-alternatives --set \$P /usr/bin/\${P}8.0; done"'
alias php81='sudo -- sh -c "for P in php php-config phpize phar phar.phar; do update-alternatives --set \$P /usr/bin/\${P}8.1; done"'
alias php82='sudo -- sh -c "for P in php php-config phpize phar phar.phar; do update-alternatives --set \$P /usr/bin/\${P}8.2; done"'
alias php83='sudo -- sh -c "for P in php php-config phpize phar phar.phar; do update-alternatives --set \$P /usr/bin/\${P}8.3; done"'
alias php84='sudo -- sh -c "for P in php php-config phpize phar phar.phar; do update-alternatives --set \$P /usr/bin/\${P}8.4; done"'

Then I can just type php82 to switch everything to v8.2, etc.
